# I can't use git on my MacBook. unable to access ~: Operation not permitted fatal: unknown error occurred while reading the configuration files

Tags: git, macos, permissions

```
user@AL02019979 test % pwd  
/Users/user/test
user@AL02019979 test % git init
warning: unable to access '/Users/user/test/.git/config': Operation not permitted
fatal: unknown error occurred while reading the configuration files
```

```
user@AL02019979 ~ % git init
hint: Using 'master' as the name for the initial branch. This default branch name
hint: is subject to change. To configure the initial branch name to use in all
hint: of your new repositories, which will suppress this warning, call:
hint: 
hint:   git config --global init.defaultBranch <name>
hint: 
hint: Names commonly chosen instead of 'master' are 'main', 'trunk' and
hint: 'development'. The just-created branch can be renamed via this command:
hint: 
hint:   git branch -m <name>
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/user/.git/
```

Git is not available in all directories except Home. I tried everything. please help me...please

here is what I tried

1. https://osxdaily.com/2018/10/09/fix-operation-not-permitted-terminal-error-macos/
2. `sudo chown -R user: /User/user`
3. delete ~/.gitconfig

If you need more information, please reply it...

Comment: Does `chmod -R u+w /User/user` help?

Comment: still not working..

Comment: Is the problem only with Git? Can you just create a directory `/User/user/test` and a file in it?

Comment: mkdir and touch operation appear to not be a problem and are working correctly

Comment: `ls -l $(which git)` to check the executable is not SUID (Set User ID).

Comment: lrwxr-xr-x  1 user  wheel  14  2  6 16:15 /usr/local/bin/git -> ../git/bin/git
I think it's executable..

Comment: It's a symlink to `/usr/local/git/bin/git`, no suid. I'm out of ideas, sorry.